# Can itertools product function find permutations on a list of dictionaries with more than one value per key?

Tags: python, dictionary, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list of dictionaries, the simplest way (that I can think of) to describe these is to consider them as possible questions and answers in a questionnaire. Each dictionary key represents a question, the list of values are possible answers to the question.

I want to find all the possible permutations of the questionnaire responses. Itertools' product function works great if it's only possible to have one answer for each question. Is there some way to also get the permutations in a case where one of the questions can have more than one answer? E.g. consider the possibility that Question3 features a multi-select checkbox control.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
#create a dict for each question in the questionnaire and the possible answer values for that question, assign those to some variable, d;
d = {
    'question1':['answer1-1','answer1-2'],
    'question2':['answer2-1','answer2-2','answer2-3','answer2-4'],
    'question3':['question3-1','question3-2','question3-3']
}
#the itertools product function gets you the various permutations, this works great if each question can only have one answer, e.g. a single-select/radio button
t=[dict(zip(d, v)) for v in product(*d.values())]
#this sticks the permutations in a dataframe with the dict keys as a header
pd.DataFrame(t).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I'm not married to itertools if it's the wrong package for the job.

Comment: `d['question3'] = list(powerset(d['question3'])` where `powerset` comes from the recipes at the end of the [documentation page for `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) should do the job

Comment: @Bakuriu but `powerset` without the empty set.

Comment: @Bakuriu, that did it. Thanks!